# Magento 1.9 "public" directory model

Tags: magento-1.9, security

I want to be confident that access to my Magento 1 code bases is restricted.

I have:

1. created a folder in my Magento root directory named `public`
2. moved `.htaccess` to `public/.htaccess`
3. created `public/index.php`
4. and created symbolic links of `public/js`, `public/skin`, and `public/media`

This setup isn't much different than creating a new Magento website in a multi-site setup. **Is there anything else I should be considering?**

Answer (score 3):

Suggestions:

- Instead of moving `.htaccess` you could also symlink it
- Same goes for `index.php`
- On top of the folders you mentionned, I would add `favicon.ico`, `errors` folder and `sitemaps` folder.

Edit: depending if you use them or not, you could add `get.php` as well as `api.php`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. To confirm, this does appear to offer greater security.